# SQL Where clause with VARCHAR date

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a MySQL DB to work with which has a `LASTUPDATE` column as VARCHAR.
This field has this format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`

I need to set up a SELECT query to find all rows after e certain date, so i was trying to use the `CONVERT` function in this way

```
SELECT * from POWER WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, LASTUPDATE) > 'CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-12-29 17:24:22')'
```

but i'm getting the error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LASTUPDATE) > 'CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-12-29 17:32:52')'' at line 1
```

I have also tried to use:

`SELECT * from POWER WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, LASTUPDATE) > '2016-12-29 17:32:52'` but i'm getting the same error

Comment: You need to use `SUBSTRING` function to get the date and parameters.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: uppercase columns and varchar dates, glad I don't work with that database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the str_to_date

```
SELECT * 
from POWER 
WHERE str_to_date(LASTUPDATE, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' ) > 
        str_to_date('2016-12-29 17:24:22', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' )
```

Comment: Note that MySQL accepts date and time literals, so you do not need another str_to_date on the right-hand side of the > operator. I have a link to MySQL documentation in my answer below.

Comment: @leeyuiwah  yes  is correct  but  the answer  is for an immediate comprhension

Answer (score 1):

**Use `str_to_date()`**

The query should use `str_to_date()` like this.  See [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) for more details

```
SELECT 
    * 
from POWER 
WHERE 
    str_to_date(LASTUPDATE, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') > '2016-12-29 17:24:22'
```

**Date and time literial**

Note that MySQL accepts date and time literals, so you do not need another `str_to_date` on the right-hand side of the `>` operator.  See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html) for more details.

**About the form `between ... and ...` on a string field storing date value**

Some suggested using the form of `between ... and ...`, such as the one
shown below.  Note that this method would work *only if* the string
values happen to use a format in which sorting the string alphabetically (in the given collation) happens to give the same sorting order as date (the format used in the original question -- `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'` -- happens to satisfy this condition, but this is not guaranteed (see an example below) for many string representations of date/time values).

```
SELECT 
    * 
from POWER 
WHERE 
    LASTUPDATE between '2016-12-29 17:24:22' AND '2016-12-31 23:59:59';
```

And it would fail if the string values are using a different format, such as these:

```
create table power (
  lastupdate varchar(40) not null default ''
) engine=innoDB;

insert into power
values
('Dec 30, 2016 07:24:22')
, ('Jan 28, 2016 07:24:22')
```

For the above, we must still use the `str_to_date()` function (this time with a `format` argument `%b %d, %Y %H:%i:%s` that is matching the format used with the string values)

```
SELECT 
    * 
from POWER 
WHERE 
    str_to_date(LASTUPDATE, '%b %d, %Y %H:%i:%s') > '2016-12-29 17:24:22';
```

I have an [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a17bc5/2) page showing the above example.

Comment: it is not a the best idea to convert a datafield in the WHERE clause. if you do that MySQL cant use a index and generate a FULL TABLE SCAN. You can also use BETWEEN: SELECT * FROM POWER WHERE LASTUPDATE BETWEEN '2016-12-29 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-29 23:59:59'

Comment: Note that the `between ... and ...` method would work _only if_ the string
values happen to use a format in which sorting the string alphabetically (in the given collation) happens to give the same sorting order as date (the format used in the original question -- `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'` -- happens to satisfy this condition, but this is not guaranteed (see an example below).

Answer (score 0):

`convert` is an MS-SQL Server function. In MySQL, you can use the [`str_to_date`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function with similar semantics:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   power
WHERE  STR_TO_DATE(lastupdate, '%Y-%m-%d %H-%i-%s') > 
       STR_TO_DATE('2016-12-29 17:24:22', '%Y-%m-%d %H-%i-%s')
```